# bypassing methods in model from two different variables in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this code in my controller and model

SessionsController

```
def create
   user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"]) 
    user.skip_password_validation = true

  unless user.present?
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
     if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
      # Log the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
    else
      # Create an error message.
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end    
  else        
    log_in user
    redirect_to user
  end
end
```

user model

```
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)

  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)  
      user.save!      
    end
  end
end
```

As i have two, different, login methods in my sessions controller I need to skip methods in my User model. I have looked in to a few things such as before filters, before actions and attribute accessors and search the web but cant seem to find out how to skip methods in the model so I can bypass those for each user variable I have assigned in the sessions controller? Ie, one for omniauth facebook and the other for just standard login.

Comment: Which method you want to skip?

Comment: Hi, i would like to skip the `def self.from_omniauth(auth)` method as the `user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)` which is the basic login is causing a `undefined method 'provder'` error, so skip the second `user` variable I have assigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question properly, in case of plain auth there would be no `env["omniauth.auth"]` set, so one might go with:

```
def create
  user = if env["omniauth.auth"]
    User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"]).tap do |u|
      u.skip_password_validation = true
    end
  else
    User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase).tap do |u|
      unless u && u.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        # Create an error message.
        flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
        render 'new'
        return
      end
    end
  end

  log_in user
  redirect_to user
end
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct! Except I replaced `u` with `user` and it worked fine Thankyou!

Comment: I have corrected the `u`/`user` glitch in the code above.

Comment: Not yet you havnt :)

Comment: You misunderstand how `tap` works and why is it there. I have had.

Comment: ok, i have not had time to go through this. but changing my code works fine. wierdly enough it worked with `u` being `user`